# 'value' is not expected in 'text' UI component

Tags: magento2, error, uicomponent, text

I try to add text item to adminhtml UI component as [described in docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-text.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">...</argument>
    <settings>...</settings>
    <dataSource ...>...</dataSource>

    <fieldset name="..._form">
        ...
        <text name="text_example" template="ui/form/field">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Text Field Example</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <disabled>false</disabled>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/text</elementTmpl>
                <value>The text value example</value>
            </settings>
        </text>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have an error in browser:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/.../view/adminhtml/ui_component/..._form.xml" is invalid:
Element 'value': This element is not expected.
Line: 63

Verify the XML and try again.
<pre>#1 Magento\Ui\Config\Reader->read() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Data.php:102]
#2 Magento\Ui\Config\Data->initData() called at [vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Data.php:136]
#3 Magento\Ui\Config\Data->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/UiComponent.php:100]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\UiComponent->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php:105]
...
```

I've checked [text.xsd](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/text.xsd) and [ui_component.xsd](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/ui_component.xsd) and I don't see `value` attribute is defined there.

What is the right way to add text item to UI form?

---

These are the text items based on [@Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) (first one) and [@Shailesh Katarmal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/34232/shailesh-katarmal) (second one) answers below:

[image]

Marius code should be slightly edited:

```
<text template="ui/form/element/text">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="inputName" xsi:type="string">text_example</item>
            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">Lorem ipsum ...</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</text>
```

but Shailesh Katarmal code can be used as is.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: have you checked the XSD?

Comment: yes, I've added links to XSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <field name="text_example" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Default text here</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Text Field Example</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <disabled>false</disabled>
            <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/text</elementTmpl>
        </settings>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowd to use the tag `value` in that specific ui component.
If you want the input to have a default value then you should make your component look like this

```
    <text name="text_example" template="ui/form/field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Default text here</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Text Field Example</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <disabled>false</disabled>
            <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/text</elementTmpl>
        </settings>
    </text>
```

Apparently the example in the docs is wrong.
If you take a look a bit higher in the docs, in the "Configuration options" section you will see that there is no "value" element specified.

Comment: `Element 'default': This element is not expected.` :(

Comment: Damn. Let me take another look.

Comment: @AlexGusev I've updated the answer. Give it another try.

Comment: PHP error is gone but JS error is came: `knockout.js:3381 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "attr: function(){return {
            name:inputName,id:uid} }"
Message: inputName is not defined
    at attr (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:4:18) ...`